# Getting an exact value from FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

```
FindMinimum[{(Sin[a]^2 + Sin[b]^2)/Sin[c]^2, 
  a + 2 b == π/2 && a + b + c == π && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b, 
  c}]
```

The numerical value obtained is:

> {0.656854, {a -> 0.427079, b -> 0.571859, c -> 2.14266}}

How can I get the exact value for `(Sin[a]^2 + Sin[b]^2)/Sin[c]^2`
which is `4*Sqrt[2]-5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear["Global`*"]

Using [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) and [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
Minimize[{(Sin[a]^2 + Sin[b]^2)/Sin[c]^2, 
   a + 2 b == π/2 && a + b + c == π && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b, 
   c}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
RootApproximant@
 First@FindMinimum[{(Sin[a]^2 + Sin[b]^2)/Sin[c]^2, 
    a + 2 b == \[Pi]/2 && a + b + c == \[Pi] && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, 
    b, c}]
```

> $4 \sqrt{2}-5$

---

EDIT:

To get the entire result:

```
MapAt[RootApproximant, 
 FindMinimum[{(Sin[a]^2 + Sin[b]^2)/Sin[c]^2, 
   a + 2 b == \[Pi]/2 && a + b + c == \[Pi] && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, b,
    c}], 1]
```

> {-5 + 4 Sqrt[2], {a -> 0.427079, b -> 0.571859, c -> 2.14266}}

Edit again

```
bc = Solve[{a + 2 b == \[Pi]/2, a + b + c == \[Pi]}, {b, c}];
fa = FullSimplify[(Sin[a]^2 + Sin[b]^2)/Sin[c]^2 /. bc];
(* the previeous problem is reduced to a simpler quesiton with output as fa = -((-2 + Cos[2 a] + Sin[a])/(1 + Sin[a]))  *)
```

Your can plot it

```
LogLinearPlot[fa, {a, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True]
```

Then, we can get its minimum value as

```
pa = Solve[D[fa, a] == 0 && 0 < a < 2 Pi, a] // Simplify
fa /. pa // FullSimplify
```

This will give the correct ruslt.

```
{{a -> \[Pi]/2}, {a -> 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[2 (1 + Sqrt[2])]]},
 {a -> 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2 (1 + Sqrt[2])]]}}

{1, -5 + 4 Sqrt[2], -5 + 4 Sqrt[2]}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `RootApproximant` result can depend on precision of the input, and if the input isn't really an approximation of a polynomial root it is likely to be completely bogus (in the sense of not actually matching the exact value), often implied by being particularly complicated, and increasing in size while input precision is raised. See output from `InputForm[RootApproximant[N[Sin[1]]]]` for instance.

Comment: Hence the name `RootApproximant`.

Comment: Yes. It's just noteworthy that it doesn't return unevaluated for limited-precision input, like in my example with machine-precision numbers it happily returns a 14th degree root.

Comment: ... comparing this with `Rationalize`, which doesn't turn arbitrary reals into long rationals without extra effort.